# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password

Tags: node.js, express, exception, promise, nodemailer

I'm sending an email through nodemailer, I'm using sequelize transaction to rollback the above task if email not sent, I'm getting the error while rejecting Promise or throwing an error.
Please help.

```
//Transaction 
await db.sequelize.transaction(async t => {
    const facility = await db.Facility.create(body, {transaction: t});
    const user = await userCmp.addUser(email.email, t); // add user
    await facilityUserCmp.addFacilityUser(facility.id, user.id, t); // add facility_user
    emailCmp.verification(user, t); // notify user

    if (user) {
        res.status(201).send({
            success: true,
            errors: [],
            data: facility
        });
    }
});
```

emailCmp.verification(user, t);  // this is the function to send an email.

sending Email code.

```
verification: (user, t) => {
    try {
        const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'SendGrid',
            auth: {
                user: 'wrong username',
                pass: 'wrong password'
            }
        });
        const mailOptions = {
            to: 'test email',
            from: 'test email',
            subject: 'test subject',
            text: 'Testing email'
        };
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
                .then((success) => {
                    console.log(success);
                }).catch((e) => {
                    throw new Error(e);
                });
    } catch (e) {
           console.log("inside catch -p---------------");
       }
```

Exception :

```
(node:10492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password
at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\******\*****\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:606:19)
at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\******\*****\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1335:34)
at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (C:\Users\******\*****\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:366:26)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\******\*****\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:762:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\******\*****\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:558:14)
at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (C:\Users\******\*****\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:709:51)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:638:20)
(node:10492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:10492) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What is not understandable? It seems like You have provided wrong username or password to send grid?

Comment: @KarlR Yes I gave the wrong username and password   to handle the exception and reject the Prmosie so my rollback works. but I'm getting above exception which is correct but rollnack is not working because unhandleprmoise issue.